# Vim: how to paste a block of text at the end of multiple lines?

Tags: vim, paste, text-manipulation

Say I have a block of text like this:

```
// Comment1
// Comment2
// Comment3
```

And I want to append each of these lines to the end of 3 corresponding lines of code:

```
foo = 1;
bar = 2;
baz = 3;
```

So that the end result is

```
foo = 1; // Comment1
bar = 2; // Comment2
baz = 3; // Comment3
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Vim?

Comment: @Flimzy, unfortunately no. From time to time comments like yours appear in Vim questions, but check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/160504

Comment: The better community for this question is https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use visual block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) to select one set of lines, then either <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> them.

Then, if you selected the foo, bar, baz lines use visual block mode again to select the first column of the comment lines and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> them into place (or if you selected the comment lines, select the last column of the foo bar baz lines and <kbd>p</kbd> them into place.

Getting the hang of positioning might take a bit of practice, but when you've got the knack you'll be flying. When you've got a block selected you can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to append e.g. spaces to the block (when appending, the new text will only appear in the top line, but when you hit esc it will magically appear in all the selected lines). Similarly, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> will do the same at the beginning of the selected block on each line.

You'll need to clean up the empty lines afterwards though.

There's also [a great vimcasts episode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/) showing these techniques in more detail.

Comment: I find this solution coupled with `:set ve=all` to be very versatile. I personally use the UnconditionalPaste plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) as it fits my need a bit better.

Comment: This does not work for me for some strange reason. My vim will still behave like I am using visual line mode when pasting (adding newlines etc.)

Comment: Be aware of the newlines and make sure you use "visual block" (Ctrl+v) to select the second block that you want to copy to the first one. If you use "visual lines" (Shift+v) to copy the second block, it will also copy the "end of line" character.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it is easy or not, you tell me. Navigate to `// Comment 1`, hit `dd` to delete. Navigate to the line with `foo = 1;` and hit `p`, to paste in below the line. Move up to `foo` again, and hit `J` to join the row. Tada.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do exactly what you describe:

```
:%s@\(\w\s\+=\s\+\(\d\+\)\)@\=submatch(1) . " // Comment" . submatch(2)@
```

Depending on what you actually need done (as opposed to the example), in practice, it might be more straightforward to block-select the "// Comment1" etc. block (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>), yank (<kbd>y</kbd>), go to the end of the code block and paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you have these two block in the same file use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to select the comments --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> , then go the first line of the other block, press <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then press <kbd>p</kbd>.

If your comments are in the clipboard run:

```
:call setreg('+',getreg('+'),'b')
```

then press <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and finally <kbd>p</kbd>.

NOTE: The `setreg()` command, the way we are using makes your clipboard blockwise, allowing you to paste it at the side of any block of the text.

You can view a gif where the guy uses the first approach slightly differently: https://codegrepr.com/question/how-do-i-paste-a-column-of-text-after-a-different-column-of-text-in-vim/