# Run KDE applet from command line (within i3wm)

Tags: linux, command-line, xorg, kde, i3-window-manager

It would be lovely to have the "Application Menu, a launcher based on cascading popup menus" as an icon in my `i3bar` to have a general overview of the packages I have installed in my system, within each categories (Internet, Games etc.) I could not figure out how to start the applet in the `i3` environment. Is there a command that could call the applet itself (may also start some KDE process that runs ONLY in the background)? Obviously, I do not want to start the whole KDE5.

I found that running `plasmashell -ws` or `plasmashell --windowed --shut-up` starts the whole KDE desktop as a window which can also manage windows started from within i3wm. However, that is such an overkill to just start one component/plasmoid. I found that `kcmshell{4,5}` can be used to call a collection of modules that are available via `kcmshell{4,5} --list`, but they are seemingly not plasmoids.

Answer (score 8):

After a thorough study on KDE5 API, I found the answer to my own question. To start kicker (Application Menu) form within a command line WITHOUT starting the whole KDE desktop, simply run:

```
plasmawindowed org.kde.plasma.kicker
```

We can also run a lot of other plasmoids. To see a list of all plasmoids installed, run both of the following:

```
kpackagetool5 --list --type Plasma/Applet -g  # system wide
kpackagetool5 --list --type Plasma/Applet     # current user
```

Here is the API page:
https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/QML2/GettingStarted

Here is a more complete API page:
https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting

Comment: Now I am trying to find out a way to put this windowed applet/plasmoid into my i3bar as a icon.

Comment: Any newer developments in this front?

Comment: I am content with the solution above (you can use `i3` to move and rescale the widget as you like), so no more news on my side. KDE or i3 might have something interesting though.

Comment: Do you use [Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper) under i3?

Comment: Nope, I haven't tried using it. If it is an plasma app, you can list it using one of the above commands, and once you find its command line name (org.kde.plasma.*), then you should be able to also only activate it within i3. As I am a heavy vim user, I mainly rely on my editor to do the pastebin job.

Comment: Off-topic, maybe: I nearly write every text with vim. How do you replicate a list of "copy-paste" entries though within it?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris It is indeed offtopic. Go https://superuser.com/questions/300362/vim-how-to-paste-a-block-of-text-at-the-end-of-multiple-lines